# New to XSLT. Having difficulty totalling some values

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I'm finding it quite difficult to figure out how to total all the subtotals that are generated from two elements (price and quantity).

Any help appreciated (including pointing out inefficient code for the bits I've done so far, I'm new and still learning so I need the help)

XML

```
<Items>
<Item ItemNumber="1251469">
    <ProductName>Cherub Baby 240ml Single - Light Blue</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Cherub Baby</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    <Price>7.99</Price>
</Item>
<Item ItemNumber="1148087">
    <ProductName>Dolby Metal-Black-Matte</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Vestal Watches</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
    <Price>67.99</Price>
</Item>
<Item ItemNumber="1351465">
    <ProductName>M OR PERFED PLAINTOE BLACK</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Rockport</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Price>96.99</Price>
</Item>
<Item ItemNumber="1150197">
    <ProductName>Vercilli Blk-Tan</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Boston Babes</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>23.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
    <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>56.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1148087">
    <ProductName>Dolby Metal-Black-Matte</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Vestal Watches</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Price>67.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1150197">
    <ProductName>Vercilli Blk-Tan</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Boston Babes</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Price>23.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1150173">
    <ProductName>Lucille Tan</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Boston Babes</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>24.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
    <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>56.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1148089">
    <ProductName>Plexi Leather-Silver-Black</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Vestal Watches</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>189.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1148096">
    <ProductName>Observer-Black-Silver-White</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Vestal Watches</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>82.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
    <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    <Price>56.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1151470">
    <ProductName>Elegant Chandelier Pearl Drop Earrings - Champaign</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Bella Krystal</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>39.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1148089">
    <ProductName>Plexi Leather-Silver-Black</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Vestal Watches</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>189.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1251465">
    <ProductName>Cherub Baby Bottle Kit - Berry</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Cherub Baby</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <Price>42.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1351468">
    <ProductName>M ES MOC OX BITTER CHOCOLATE</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Rockport</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>7</Quantity>
    <Price>72.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
    <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>56.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1251464">
    <ProductName>Apple Pattern T-Shirt-Blue</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Avahna</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>14.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1351464">
    <ProductName>W ZANA BIKE FRONT OXFORD SATIN NICKEL</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Rockport</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>59.99</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemNumber="1251464">
    <ProductName>Cherub Baby Bottle Kit - Citrus</ProductName>
    <ProviderName>Cherub Baby</ProviderName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>42.99</Price>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Sales amount by provider</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Sales amount by provider</h2>
<table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="ProviderName">
    <xsl:sort select="ProviderName"/>
        <tr bgcolor="#99cc00">
            <td colspan="4">Provider: <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Number</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@ItemNumber">
        <xsl:sort select="@ItemNumber"/>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@ItemNumber"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Quantity)"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="round(Price * (sum(current-group()/Quantity )))"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:variable name="SubTotals">
           <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@ItemNumber">
              <subTotal><xsl:value-of select="round(Price * (sum(current-group()/Quantity )))"/></subTotal>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Sub-total</b></td>
            <td>
            <TotalValue>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($SubTotals/subTotal)"/>
            </TotalValue>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Grand-total</b></td>
        <td>
            <!-- The last bit I cant figure out -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you stuck on XSLT 1.0, or can you use XSLT 2.0? EDIT: for-each-group is only available on XSLT 2.0, so that's what you're using ;-)

Comment: XSLT 2.0 is actually preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Grand-total</b></td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(for $item in (/Items/Item) return $item/Quantity * $item/Price)" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

It uses a [for expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions) to calculate each subtotal, along with the `sum` function to yield the grand total.

Comment: By the way, if you want to round the result to a particular decimal precision, have a look at this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/xslt-cookbook/0596003722/ch02s02.html.